# PhoneGap Build does not compress resources in APK

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

After build in PG build with icon and splash screens recourcess: IPA size is ~ 2M, and APK size is ~ 100M,

[image]

so resource in APK are not compressed

[image]

in IPA they are

[image]

What can be the reason?

Comment: [cross-posted here](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/pg-build-does-not-compress-user-resouces-in-apk)

Answer (score 0):

Well I just solved by removing assets from build using .pgbomit